# Killed process that didn't show sign of memory leaks?

Tags: php, memory, memory-leaks

I have a script that runs in the background written in PHP that connects to other servers multiple times (one by one).

I specially worked on the memory leaks in order to properly close the resources used, and I have implemented a real time output of what the script is using, with the `memory_get_usage()` function from PHP.

The script runned for about an hour, and the memory indicated something around 340kb (up to 360kb max).

But then, it stopped. Without any error message or anything else.

When I looked at `dmesg`, here what I saw :

> Out of memory: Kill process 3147 (php5) score 905 or sacrifice child
>
> Killed process 3147 (php5) total-vm:651064kB, anon-rss:475032kB,
>   file-rss:48kB

(*For information, I have a 512Mb Digital Ocean server*)

With a list of process before, including a message with `lowmem_reserve`

I'm starting to think that the script contains some memory leak. Could you confirm this? But if that's the case, why `memory_get_usage` didn't increased? is it reliable? Is there a better way to trace the potential memory leaks?

UPDATE 1: Here's the current state of my server

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
 2283 root      20   0 67104 6724  900 S   0,0  1,3   0:05.97 fail2ban-server   
 4100 cyril     20   0 21416 4156 1672 S   0,0  0,8   0:00.16 bash              
 4094 root      20   0 81856 3976 3136 S   0,0  0,8   0:00.00 sshd              
 4192 root      20   0 20568 3384 1732 S   0,0  0,7   0:00.09 bash              
 2370 root      20   0 62032 2264 1196 S   0,0  0,4   0:00.13 console-kit-dae   
 4099 cyril     20   0 81856 1676  848 S   0,0  0,3   0:00.00 sshd
```

Comment: That's not PHP killing the script. it's the system itself picking a sacrificial child because the system as a whole ran out of memory, and your script just happen to get chosen.

Comment: But the server does nothing except working on this script (I took it only to execute this script)

Comment: Run `top` and then hit Shift + M should show you what is running sorted by highest memory usage

Comment: I updated my question with the top command.